# Tkinter Overlapping Label Text

Tags: python, tkinter

I have just started utilizing Python's tkinter module to create some basic GUIs. In the GUI shown below, the user is prompted to upload the cafe image and subsequent cafe name will appear. However, I have not found a convenient way to clear the cafe label text for when the user upload another cafe image and classify again. I have the full code attached below.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from h5py import File

def upload():
    global img
    global filename
    f_types = [('Png files', '*.png')]
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetype=f_types)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = filename)
    e1 = tk.Label(window)
    e1.place(x=50, y=150)
    e1['image'] = img
    window.configure(background = '#CDCDCD')
    show_classify_button()
    
def show_classify_button():
    classify_btn = tk.Button(window, text='Classify Image', command=classification)
    classify_btn.place(x=250, y=400)
    classify_btn.configure(background = '#364156', foreground = 'white', font=('cambria', 15, 'bold') )

def classification():
    matrix = []
    image = cv2.imread(filename, 0)
    array = np.array(image)
    flatten_array = array.flatten()
    matrix.append(flatten_array)
    X = pca.transform(matrix)
    pred = clf.predict(X)
    if pred == 0:
        Label(window, text='Casa De Cafe', font='Cambria 20 bold', background = '#CDCDCD', foreground = '#364156').place(x=170, y=300)
        
    elif pred == 1:
        Label(window, text='Coffeology', font='Cambria 20 bold', background = '#CDCDCD', foreground = '#364156').place(x=170, y=300)
        
    else:
        Label(window, text='Mori Cafe', font='Cambria 20 bold', background = '#CDCDCD', foreground = '#364156').place(x=170, y=300)
             
    
def main_account_screen():
    global window
    window = Tk()
    window.title('Cafe Recognition System')
    window.geometry('500x500')
    window.configure(background = '#CDCDCD')
    
    Label(window, text='Cafe Recognition System', font='Cambria 20 bold', background = '#CDCDCD', foreground = '#364156').place(x=110, y=50)
    
    button = tk.Button(window, text='Upload', command=upload)
    button.place(x=130, y=400)
    button.configure(background = '#364156', foreground = 'white', font=('cambria', 15, 'bold') )
    
    window.mainloop()
    
main_account_screen()
```

Comment: I don't know what the "cafe label" is, but you can change its text by calling the widget's [`config()`](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/universal.html) method.

Comment: @martineau my cafe label is 0, 1 and 2 and can i ask which line of code need to call the `config()`? Is it after the `Label()`? like this `Label.config()`?

Comment: Not sure what "my cafe label is 0, 1 and 2" means, sorry. If you save a `Label` when it is created in a variable, say `my_label1 = tk.Label(…)`, you can change the text on it later using `my_label1.config(text="new text")`. So, in your own words, do this "when the user upload another cafe image and classify again".

Comment: i added 2 missing imports, but there are other undefined variables: `pca` and `clf`, what are those please ?

Comment: In your `main_account_screen()` create a *blank* `Label` to hold the text based on the `pred` value later, then in the `classification()` function use the `config()` method to change set the text of that `Label` to what it should be. Be careful when initially creating the `Label` because the `place()` layout method does **not** return a value (i.e. it returns `None`).

Comment: @D.L `pca` and `clf` is the machine learning algorithm which Ididn't show in this code

Comment: @martineau alright thanks for your classification, the problem is solved.